# Custom Post Type URL Change - (portfolio using portfolio categories)

Tags: custom-post-types

I wonder if you could help me.

I'm using a theme which has `portfolio` as a custom post type. The portfolio items can be categorised in a similar way to standard posts.

Currently, theme outputs portfolio URLs in the following format:

```
mysite.com/portfolio/portfolio-post
```

...where `portfolio-name` is simply the post title. the middle section of the URL remains static.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
mysite.com/portfolio-category/portfolio-post
```

...where the `portfolio-category` proportion of the URL is taken from the portfolio category.

Each portfolio post will only be assigned to a single portfolio category at any one time.

I can send code examples across if this makes it easier for you to understand what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the permalinks settings as well as the portfolio settings. The permalinks settings allow you to create a custom URL-scheme that you can use for many post types.

Although I don't know the exact theme you're using, many have options to customize the URL of the portfolio in a portfolio settings page.

Finally, if none of those work, you can look at the theme's files (assuming you have some experience editing PHP) and find where the custom post type is being created. Depending on how the theme creator created the custom post type, it may be as simple as changing a line or two in the theme editor.

Best of luck to you!